# iPhone App installs to 90% and then dies

Tags: iphone, objective-c, testflight

I am trying to install an app from TestFlight.  It installs to 90% and then it just fails.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are a few things but this can commonly happen if the device you are installing to is not in the provisioning profile that the app was signed with - you can use Xcode or a [quicklook plugin](http://www.macmation.com/blog/2011/10/quicklook-plugin-for-mobile-provision-files/) like this to see what devices are on the profile

Comment: I just recently had an issue like this. It turned out that the device had some old provisioning profiles installed with the same App-ID that seemed to mess things up. Have a look into The list of currently installed provisioning profiles on the device and remove old ones, if applicable.

Comment: This also can be caused if the device does not have the correct iOS version (_for example, iOS 5.0+ app, but device is iOS 4.3.2_)

Comment: For what it's worth, the first ~90% of the progress bar is the downloading, so if it dies after that, there is a problem at the installation/verification phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the application download hits 90% it generally means the download has completed and iOS was unable to extract and install the build.

There are many reasons why this happens, most of which we catch with upload or install time validations, unfortunately there are a few cases we do not or are unable to detect.

Here is our help article discussing some of the scenarios.

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829652-received-an-unable-to-download-application-message-what-does-this-mean-?topicname=Mobile